# One maxlength for multiple text fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maxlength

Hi say I have two text fields. I want to have just one maxlength for both of them. Wherein, for example 300 is the maxlength. And that is for both text fields. Is it possible to have 1 maxlength for multiple fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

You will need to use jquery/javascript and client side validation.  As a starting point

Something like

```
$('#text_field_1, #text_field_2').blur(function(){
  if($('#text_field_1').val() + $('#text_field_2').val() > 300){
    alert("Text Field max length has been reached");
  }
});
```

Building on that example you'll want to have a listener on form submission $().submit that will return false, show an error message, and stop submitting the form if the max length is greater that allowed.

Comment: Thanks. But i want it to be like... if I have 300 maxlength.. if i type in text field 1 it will decrease and if i type to text field 2, the 300 will also decrease. Seems like theyre using just one maxlength.

Comment: I dont have to set maxlength anymore?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to set it as the javascript will handle the maxlength for both fields.  The only reason to still set it would be if you also want an individual limit on each text field as well.